# Javascript conditional execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [conditional javascript code not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997966/conditional-javascript-code-not-executing)

Hi, how can I achieve this:

```
$('x').live("touchstart", function (e) { 
//do stuff
if (event= ontouchmove){
//do stuff
}
else (event= ontouchend){
//do stuff
}
```

So after a touchstart, either ontouchmove fires stuff or ontouchend, but if ontouchmove fires ontouchend does not. an event listener or something?

Thanks for your help (and yes the code is not correct but serves as an example :p)

EDIT: tried one of your answers but it still does not work...

```
$('input').live("touchstart", function (e) {$(this).addClass('click')});

            $('input').live("touchmove,touchend", function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'touchmove'){
            $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
            $('.click').removeClass('click');}

            else{var inputvalue = $(this).val()
             $('input[value="' + inputvalue + '"] + label').css({
                    '-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.3s linear',
                    'opacity': '0'
                });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('input[value="' + inputvalue + '"]  + label').css({'-webkit-transition': '0',
                    'opacity': '1'});
            $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
            $('.click').removeClass('click');
            }, 300);}
        });
```