# conditional javascript code not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, conditional-statements, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know why this code might not work? touchmove and touchend do not execute only touchstart because that's a seperate event and function :)

```
$('input').live("touchstart", function (e) {$(this).addClass('click')});

$('input').live("touchmove,touchend", function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'touchmove'){
       $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
       $('.click').removeClass('click');
    }
    else{var inputvalue = $(this).val()
       $('input[value="' + inputvalue + '"] + label').css({
          '-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.3s linear',
          'opacity': '0'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
        $('input[value="' + inputvalue + '"]  + label').css({'-webkit-transition': '0','opacity': '1'});
            $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
            $('.click').removeClass('click');
        }, 300);}
    });
```

Thanks a lot for any attempt :)

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to use the [touchstart](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/touchstart) plugin?

Comment: no plugin, doing it myself :)

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997283/javascript-conditional-execution)? What did you expect? How did it fail? What have you tried?

Comment: the difference is that the first question what about the method, this one is general code :). It might me my script that is faulty, not the method. Nothing executes, not the touchmove nor the touchend.

Comment: .live("touchmove,touchend") ... are you allowed to have comma separated events? I've always used space delimited names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event names in the first argument to ".live()" need to be separated by **spaces**, not commas.

```
$('input').live("touchmove touchend", function (e) {
```

Comment: yes works :D. But somehow touchend still executes when it occurs even when touchmove has fired. Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm ... are you **sure** that's happening?  It might help to put in some `console.log()` calls or something to make sure that there's not a real "touchend" event being fired.  Your code pretty clearly tests the event type, so it's hard to understand how it could erroneously execute the "touchend" code unless it's really a "touchend" event ...

Comment: Well a real touchend occurs but my goal was to only let the touchend code execute if no touchmove event had happened before that.

Comment: Well the code as written simply can't do that - it just checks the *current* event's type.  You could maintain some sort of state in a global variable and use that to decide when to do the "touchend" work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
$('x').live("ontouchmove, ontouchend", function (e) { 
  //do stuff
  if (e.type == 'ontouchmove'){
    //do stuff
  }
  else{
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: dude, this is what I need and it looks awesome, but it does not work (look at example above). Neither event gets fired...

Comment: @SnippetSpace sorry, it should be no comma between the events. I'm more used to selectors than events, I guess :p

Answer (score 0):

First off, your event variable should be the parameter `e` rather than `event`.

Second, when testing for equality, you need two equals signs: `==`. One equals sign is the assignment operator.

Comment: it was an example, nothing real as i wrote in my post

Answer (score -1):

What does the console say when you open your site / trying to run the method? :)

//Gerner

Comment: This is not really an answer; it should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @ Pointy Your are totally right, but i couldnt find the "add comment" button, Its only on my own answer. 
I wrote anyway instead of just leave.. 

@SnippetSpace I cant help you any more than Pointy already has. Sorry. The console always rescues me ;)